# foreach loop, check for approval, display error array

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table with checkboxes and a button that allows users to be "approved", a simple 1 in the database marks they have been approved. I want to first check to see if the user is ALREADY approved, just so that I can display an error message. However what ends up happening in this code is that for some reason the code executes the underlying sql, but displays the error message as is, or when `!$check` always display a success message. I have tried different variations but I have a feeling the problem is with my $check sql logic. I just can't seem to see it.

```
if ($_POST['doApprove'] == 'Approve') {
    if (!empty($_POST['u'])) {
        foreach ($_POST['u'] as $uid) {
            $id = filter($uid);
            $username[] = get_user_name_from_id($id);
            $check = Nemesis::select("approved", "users", "id = '{$id}' AND approved <> '1'");  // issue?
            $set_approve = Nemesis::update("users", "approved = '1'", "id = '{$id}'");
            if ($check) { // issue?
                $fail[] = $username;
            } elseif (!$set_approve) {
                $fail[] = $username;
            } else {
                $pass[] = $username;
                $user_details = Nemesis::select("*", "users", "id = '{$id}'");
                $ud_row = $user_details->fetch_assoc();
                authMail('register', $ud_row['user_email'], $ud_row['pwd'], $ud_row['user_name'], NULL, 'admin');
            }
        }
    }
    $msg = new Messages();
    if (!empty($pass)) {
        $passed = implode(', ', $pass);
        $message = "Approved: {$passed}";
        $msg->add('s', $message);
    }
    if(!empty($fail)){
        $failure = implode(', ', $fail);
        $message = "Could not approve {$failure}";
        $msg->add('e', $message);
    }
    redirect('users.php');
}
```

Comment: `Nemesis`? Presumably that just does a templated query?

Comment: yea the sql for select is SELECT this FROM that WHERE this AND that

Comment: Is `approved` a text field?

Comment: int(1) field in database

Comment: Then you don't need quotes around the value, they are for textual or date-based values.  Numbers, integers at least, require no quotes. Same in the update and anywhere else.

Comment: You don't need the `AND approved <> 1` anyhow, as that would make `$check` NULL or empty if the user was not approved, when what you want is the value of `approved`.  So just have the ID on the where.

Comment: ok I think I have it then (posted working)

Comment: Why make so many individual queries?  You can run a select for all ID's at once and and UPDATE for all ID's at once, and reduce this down to two queries.

Comment: solid point, thank you. I am just not sure how to do it. I would suppose you would have to use to the foreach to get all the ID's but then I'm lost at the point where you have to build the which ones worked and which ones didn't arrays for whether or not the query or check failed.

Comment: feel free to improve :)

Answer (score 1):

```
   if ($_POST['doApprove'] == 'Approve') {
    if (!empty($_POST['u'])) {
        foreach ($_POST['u'] as $uid) {
            $id = filter($uid);
            $username[] = get_user_name_from_id($id);
            $check = Nemesis::select("*", "users", "id = '{$id}'");
            $ud_row = $user_details->fetch_assoc();
            $set_approve = Nemesis::update("users", "approved = '1'", "id = '{$id}'");
            if ($ud_row['approved'] || !$set_approve) {
                $fail[] = $username;
            } else {
                $pass[] = $username;
                authMail('register', $ud_row['user_email'], $ud_row['pwd'], $ud_row['user_name'], NULL, 'admin');
            }
        }
    }
    $msg = new Messages();
    if (!empty($pass)) {
        $passed = implode(', ', $pass);
        $message = "Approved: {$passed}";
        $msg->add('s', $message);
    }
    if(!empty($fail)){
        $failure = implode(', ', $fail);
        $message = "Could not approve {$failure}";
        $msg->add('e', $message);
    }
    redirect('users.php');
}
```